Python MySQL can't connect for unknown reason
When I try to use python to connect to my MySQL database, an error shows for an unknown reason:
dTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1105, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 953, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 937, in run_command
    app: WSGIApplication = info.load_app()
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 335, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 245, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sql_code
  File "/app/sql_code.py", line 4, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 322, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1399, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 339, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)

these are the files for the python connector (Moddified for censorship of sensitive info)
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="USERNAME_DATABASE",
    password="root_pass",
    database="mydatabase"
)

and the moddified MYSQL file (docker):
FROM mysql:latest

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

COPY ./ex_db.sql /docker-entyypoint-initdb.d/

ENV MYSQL_HOST=localhost

ENV MYSQL_USER=USERNAME_DATABASE

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_pass

ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase

EXPOSE 3306


Both are being run in docker with the latest version
The above code is supposed to connect without error

The error says you cannot connect to the port.  Is the mysql server running?  Not sure what image that is but on Debian I would do ss -l  sport = :3306 to see if anything is listening on the port.  If not then systemctl status mysql (change service name if needed).

is the mysql server is running? maybe you can check it with this command: sudo systemctl status mysql or sudo service mysql status

Socket errno 99 (number at the end of the error message) indicates pytnon could not bind to socket interface. Please try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Docker container is MySQL for mysql and python:latest for python (with libraries)

container for python is python:latest and container for mysql is mysql:latest

Update: Fixed it, had to set host='' in python code to mysql service name and not localhost or ip address. Thanks to those who tried to help me.
